# Marrying boys with girls

Tags: graph-theory, induction, bipartite-graphs

I’ve been working on this question for a few days now and I’m getting very confused and unsure how to progress.
I’d like to show that if there are $n$ boys and $n$ girls in a village such that every group of $k$ boys knows at least $k$ girls, that I can marry each girl with a boy she knows.
For $n=1$ there is trivially one possibility for matching boy with girl. For $n=2$ I’ve shown using bipartite graphs that there are $7$ options for knowing each other and for each possibility I can find suitable marriage arrangements.

The problem starts with $n=3$. There are so many possible graphs to draw that you need to start proving it more rigorously in writing. I considered the case in which the fewest no. of girls any of the boy knows is $1,2,3$ separately and found it worked in each case.

Now for $n=4$ it is getting very hard. If it is very hard for $n=4$ then I’m not sure where to even start the general $n=k$ case to prove it by induction.

I thought about trying to write an algorithm to turn a suitable ‘knowledge of each other’ graph into a ‘marriage graph’.

I thought: consider the boys who know only one girl and pair them up. These girls will be distinct because all these boys must know as many girls. Then consider the boys who know two girls and so on. But this is very longwinded and I find myself lost regularly.

Would someone be able to tell me where I may be going wrong and help me start going in the right direction?

Comment: May be off-topic, but the question reminded me of the [stable marriage problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qcv1IqHWAzg).

Comment: I don’t the problems are related to each other

Comment: That's why I said it 'may be off-topic' :)

Comment: An interesting video it is all the same. I watched it the other day :)

Answer (score 1):

The statement you want to prove is essentially [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem). With the conditions you state, this theorem states that it is always possible to match the boys to the girls, and since the numbers on both sides are equal, no girl is left unpaired.

Comment: I believe you may be right. Now I’m confused on why I would be asked to find the answer to a question if the answer is simply “yes” because of Hall’s marriage theorem. Doesn’t seem as big of a challenge as it should be. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Anteater23 You can just use the proof there.

Comment: Do you think my induction idea of a proof would have worked?

Comment: Also do you think I’d be able to improve the answer to be able to find the number of possible ways to arrange the marriages? Are there other avenues I could investigate that you are aware of?

Comment: @Anteater23 Induction is used to prove one direction of Hall's theorem. Counting the number of ways is a whole different problem.

Comment: Well for n=2 there are 7 possible way of the boys and girls knowing each other. By halls theorem, each possibility satisfies the condition and therefore each possibility has a marriage graph associated with it. Therefore at least 7 ways unless two knowing possibilities lead to same marriage ‍♂️